# Set new field with different value for each document in a collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which has the following documents like so:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed113d483cc872"), "Company" : "C1", "Revenue" : 100},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed23232346c112"), "Company" : "C2", "Revenue" : 200},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed113d483c3872"), "Company" : "C3", "Revenue" : 300},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed113d434gjb46"), "Company" : "C4", "Revenue" : 400}
```

I want to add another field to all the documents such that each field has a different value.
So I want to achieve the below:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed113d483cc872"), "Company" : "C1", "Revenue" : 100, "Profit": 50},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed23232346c112"), "Company" : "C2", "Revenue" : 200, "Profit": 100},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed113d483c3872"), "Company" : "C3", "Revenue" : 300, "Profit": 150},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2c48ed113d434gjb46"), "Company" : "C4", "Revenue" : 400, "Profit": 200}
```

I have a object which has the mapping between id and profit fields like this:

```
profits = {
    '5f2c48ed113d483cc872': 50,
    '5f2c48ed23232346c112': 100,
    '5f2c48ed113d483c3872': 150,
    '5f2c48ed113d434gjb46': 200
}
```

Can this be done using the updateMany or other options available in mongodb? The collection has thousands of documents the above just being an example.
(PS: I am using mongoose)

Comment: Bulk write is one option

Comment: Can it work even if the collection has thousands of documents?

Comment: Yes. That's the purpose of it.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask can you share an example please.

Comment: I suggest you to go 9ver the document anr post a specific problem so that anyone can help.